# How can I fix the alignment of complex combinations of GraphicsGrid / GraphicsRow plots?

Tags: plotting, grid-layouts, alignment

I am having problems joining multiple plots using GraphicsRow and GraphicsGrid.
The issue is that Mathematica (v12.1) rescales arbitrarily my plots when I try to combine them. The issue arises when I try to combine the output of GraphicsGrid with another plot using again GraphicsGrid/GraphicsRow, even if (I believe) I properly take into accout image sizes and paddings.

My goal is the following: After I put six identical plots in grid, I would like to add a seventh plot to the right, which has different dimensions and then export everything to .pdf.

I understand that if I want to preserve the dimensions of the plots with GraphicsGrid/GraphicsRow, I have to correctly specify the aspect ratio and ImageSize of all the plots.
I define the image sizes of my plots to be the sum of the frame size and image padding, like in the following code:

```
data = Table[RandomReal[], {10}]; (* Some data to plot *)

(* Defining relevant dimensions for plot 1*)
framex1 = 100;
framey1 = 100;

paddingx1 = {50, 10};
paddingy1 = {50, 10};

imagepadding1 = {paddingx1, paddingy1}
imagesize1 = {framex1 + Total[paddingx1], framey1 + Total[paddingy1]}


plot1 = ListPlot[data, PlotMarkers -> Automatic,
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"foo", "bar"},
  AspectRatio -> framey1/framex1, ImageSize -> imagesize1, 
  ImagePadding -> imagepadding1]
```

This code produces this plot:

[image]

Then I put six copies of this plot in a grid:

```
gridplot = 
 GraphicsGrid[{{plot1, plot1, plot1}, {plot1, plot1, plot1}}, 
  Spacings -> 0, ImageSize -> {3 imagesize1[[1]], 2 imagesize1[[2]]}]
```

This works fine. In this case gridplot actually shows 6 identical copies of plot1, with the correct size. The result is:

[image]

Now I consider the additional plot. I am careful to set the vertical size to be equal to the one of gridplot, setting the vertical padding accordingly:

```
(* Defining relevant dimensions for plot 2*)
framex2 = 100;
framey2 = 150;

paddingx2 = {50, 10};
paddingy2 = {(2 imagesize1[[2]] - framey2)/
    2, (2 imagesize1[[2]] - framey2)/2};

imagepadding2 = {paddingx2, paddingy2}
imagesize2 = {framex2 + Total[paddingx2], 2 imagesize1[[2]]}


plot2 = ListPlot[data, PlotMarkers -> Automatic,
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"foo", "bar"},
  AspectRatio -> framey2/framex2, ImageSize -> imagesize2, 
  ImagePadding -> imagepadding2]
```

Now, if I put gridplot and plot2 side-by-side, I see that the dimensions are correct. In particular the list

```
{gridplot, plot2}
```

gives:

[image]

However, If I now use GraphicsRow the plots are different and the image padding is messed up!

```
plot = GraphicsRow[{gridplot, plot2}, Spacings -> 0, 
  ImageSize -> {3 imagesize1[[1]] + imagesize2[[1]], 
    2 imagesize1[[2]]}]
```

[image]

What am I getting wrong? I have the feeling it might have to do with ImagePadding passed to GraphicsRow/GraphicsGrid.

One solution would be to rasterize the images before using GraphicsRow/GraphicsGrid, but this would prevent to export the final result in vectorial form.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution

```
plot1 = With[{XZ = 100, YZ = 100}, 
   ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"foo", "bar"}, 
    PlotMarkers -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Automatic -> {XZ, YZ}, 
    ImagePadding -> 80]];
plot2 = With[{XZ = 100, YZ = 203}, 
   ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
    FrameLabel -> {"foo", "bar"}, ImageSize -> Automatic -> {XZ, YZ}, 
    ImagePadding -> 80]];
f = Grid[{{plot1, plot1, plot1}, {plot1, plot1, plot1}}, 
   Spacings -> {-12, -12}];
Grid[{{f, plot2}}, Spacings -> {-7, -12.}, BaselinePosition -> Bottom]
```

[image]

you can also do the other way

```
plot1 = With[{XZ = 100, YZ = 100}, 
   ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"foo", "bar"}, 
    PlotMarkers -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Automatic -> {XZ, YZ}, 
    ImagePadding -> 80]];
plot2 = With[{XZ = 310, YZ = 100}, 
   ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
    FrameLabel -> {"foo", "bar"}, ImageSize -> Automatic -> {XZ, YZ}, 
    ImagePadding -> 80]];
f = Grid[{{plot1, plot1, plot1}, {plot1, plot1, plot1}}, 
   Spacings -> {-12, -12}];
Grid[{{f}, {plot2}}, Spacings -> {-12, -7.}, 
 BaselinePosition -> Bottom]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this actually solves the problem because we are using Grid instead of GraphicsGrid. Indeed, if you try to export the output of Grid/Row/Column to pdf it produces the correct output with the correct proportions, even with my example. I don't know why GraphicsGrid still doesn't work, though. Thanks!

Comment: I see, I don not know why is that happening!